# Macro in Tex Programming

Tags: macros, tex-core

I am confused whether the below macro is for section or what? If yes can anybody help me to explain this piece of code

```
 \def\Section #1 \par
    {
    \bigbreak\vskip\parskip
    \need 1.5 in
    \global\advance\secno by 1
    \subno=0\subsubno=0
    \noindent
    {\SectionTitleFont \the\secno.\hskip 1em #1}
    \par
    }
```

Comment: It certainly looks like a it's supposed to make a new section, but it's not plain TeX or standard Latex.  For example I don't think that either defines a `\need` command.  Can you give some more context?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's something like setting of section heading, but nothing more. I would use the documentclass `article` and `\section` instead of this `\Section` command. In Addition, you should read an introductory text on LaTeX

Comment: What's the source of this macro? A package? If so, which one?

Comment: I was studying about tex and found this example. Can you please explain me what is happening in this example or with some other example of macro.

Comment: @user69898 Without so more more context we can't explain this macro, at least not with confidence. As already noted, it's not a standard plain TeX macro and it's not one from LaTeX or ConTeXt either. So we need some clue as to where you found it, at least. Certainly the name indicates a sectioning command.

Comment: Ah: I found http://socs.acadiau.ca/~jdiamond/tex-reference-material/tex-intro.pdf. It says there 'examine this example
only if you enjoy programming and plan to use (plain) TeX'.  It looks to be a bit of a hodge-podge introduction. Notably, this code snippet seems to be a demo with no further examination or source: as such I would not choose to use it to learn from.

Comment: The macro includes two potential problems. First one is at the beginning of the title text. When we write `\Subsection Plus something <empty line>` then the `\hskip 1em` is followed by `Plus` (i.e. the reserved word in `\hskip` parameter). The error "Missing number treated as zero" occurs. The second problem is at the end of the title parameter. After `\Section An introduction to \TeX <empty line>` there is no space at the end of the title and the text cannot be separated by `<space>\par`.

Answer (score 11):

The macro `\Section` has an argument delimited by a space and a `\par` token, so it's supposed to be called like

```
\Section Whatever title I want

The text of the section following the title.
```

Note the blank line after the end of the section title.

The macro will store `Whatever title I want` (the actual title, of course) discarding the space produced by the end of line as `#1`.

Now the macro executes

1. `\bigbreak`, which issues `\par` and then examines the last vertical space; if this space is less than `\bigskipamount`, TeX removes it and inserts, in its place, a penalty of value -200 and `\bigskip`, making this quite a good point for breaking a page;
2. `\need 1.5in` that's not defined in Plain TeX, but seems to be aimed at looking into the current values of `\pagegoal` and `\pagetotal`; if the difference between the former and the latter is less than 1.5in, a `\vfill\eject` command is probably issued; possible definition

   ```
   \def\need{\afterassignment\checkneed\dimen0 }
   \def\checkneed{\advance\dimen0 by \pagetotal
     \ifdim\dimen0>\pagegoal \vfill\eject\fi}
   ```

   or just `\eject` if pages are to be filled up.
3. The counters `\secno` is advanced by 1; this is supposed to contain the section number; the counters `\subno` and `\subsubno`, that are supposed to contain the subsection and subsubsection numbers are set to 0.
4. `\noindent` starts a paragraph; the the title is set using `\SectionTitleFont` (a font choice command to be defined) preceded by the section number and a quad of space; grouping ensures the font setting does not propagate.
5. `\par` makes a new paragraph.

Note that 1.5in is supposed to ensure that the section title, the interline skip and at least two lines of the subsequent paragraph fit.

---

As wipet correctly remarks in a comment, this macro has a few defects.

- If the title is `Good programming in \TeX`, an unscrutable error would be issued

  ```
  Runaway argument?
  Good programming in \TeX 
  ! Paragraph ended before \Section was complete.
  <to be read again> 
                     \par
  ```

  There is no need to have `<space>\par` as the delimiter, because the trailing space would be removed anyway by the final `\par` in the replacement text, provided we remove the space in the replacement text.
- An even more unscrutable error would be issued by a title such as `Plusvalence`:

  ```
  ! Missing number, treated as zero.
  <to be read again> 
                     v
  <argument> Plusv
                  alence
  ```

  because TeX would see `\hskip 1em Plusvalence` and interpret `Plus` as a keyword.

Fixed code:

```
\def\Section #1\par
  {%
   \bigbreak\vskip\parskip
   \need 1.5 in
   \global\advance\secno by 1
   \subno=0\subsubno=0
   \noindent
   {\SectionTitleFont \the\secno.\hskip 1em\relax #1}\par
  }
```

Comment: +1  for the forensic analysis of code remains. There is no a badge for that? `:)`